# C# computationally expensive , how to make it faster

Tags: c#, .net, performance, multidimensional-array

I know its a dumb question to ask about , why this code minX is computationally expensive, but i thought, someone might inform me of my mistake. Thanks

```
// getMap is a 2 dimentional array of type short I need to find maxX,minX,maxY,minY 
//Can't use Math.Min , as it will get the lower bound i.e 0, i want values after filtering
for (int X = 0; X < getMap.GetLength(0); X++)
{       
    for (int Y = 0; Y < getMap.GetLength(1); Y++)
    {           
        if((short)getMap.GetValue(X,Y) !=  0)
        {
           //if i take it out, it works fine ,I need to 
            if (minX > X )
                minX = X;
            else
                X = minX;
        // Prints some stuff and does other computation 
        }
    }
}
// Draws image
```

Comment: It's computationally expensive because it's iterating over every element in a 2D array. What more are you looking for?

Comment: Why are you changing the value of the loop variable X inside the inner loop?

Comment: This will help get your question answered: write a table of values in your 2D array. Then let us know what you are looking for as a result. Just for a starter...

Comment: Computationally expensive is a nice understatement for "doesn't terminate".

Answer (score 4):

the `else X = minX;` part doesn't make much sense. It can cause an endless loop because you're setting back the loop variable `X` to a lower value.

Your code will only terminate if at most 1 column contains a non zero value(assuming you initialized minX to a large value).

For example assume that both the `X=0` and the `X=1` column contain a non zero value somewhere. Then when it hits the non zero value in the 0 column `minX` is set to 0. Then later it hits the non zero value with `X=1` notices that `minX>X` is false and sets X back to 0. And repeat forever.

Comment: It would seem that this would create an infinite loop in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how `(short)getMap.GetValue(X,Y)` compares to just `getmap[X,Y]` but is seems over-complicated.

What you can do is to replace  `short[,] getMap`  with  `short[][] getMap`.

Array-of-array (jagged arrays) are ususally faster in these nested loop scenarios because the Jitter can optimize range checking better.

Comment: I would guess that `getMap.GetValue` causes each item to be boxed and then the cast unboxes it. If there are a lot of values, all those boxing/unboxing operations will chew up processor cycles.

Comment: getMap() has a value, i am filtering out anything more than 0 to be used in computing min and max values

Comment: @Don: Yes it has a value but that's no reason to call GetValue(). But read Chaos's answer first. Your code is flawed.

Comment: Thanks guys , replaced it  minX = Math.Min(minX, X);
                        minY = Math.Min(minY, Y);
                        maxX = Math.Max(maxX, X);
                        maxY = Math.Max(maxY, Y);